# Can't vertically center text in round button

Tags: html, css, centering

I've been trying to create a simple round button that rotates 90 degrees when you hover over it. I've got it working for the most part, but the `+` inside the button doesn't seem to be centered properly even though  I am using `align-items: center;` which I thought would perfectly center the text inside the element vertically.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid lime;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: lime;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
```

As you can see from the rotation, it definitely is not centered correctly. Any tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: Apparently others aren't seeing my issue so here is a GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRLEi.jpg

Comment: It looks centered to me. What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome. You should test in different browsers.

Comment: Using Chrome. When hovering over the button, the plus sign seems to rotate weirdly instead of staying in place. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: It seems to happen for me on Firefox as well.

Comment: Looks like a normal rotation to me. What do you mean by "weirdly"? When I hover over it, it rotates smoothly 90 degrees clockwise, and when I move off it rotates 90 degrees ccw. You mentioned an issue with centering, which I don't see.

Comment: @lurker I recorded a GIF of what I am seeing: https://imgur.com/a/K9IXmlN

Comment: That's interesting. That's what I saw in the original answer given by symlink before it was changed to use an icon. And your solution doesn't do that in my Chrome browser in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a plus icon from a site like fontawesome.com and center it with flex:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
 background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid lime;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: lime;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

button > .fa-plus{
  font-size:16px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button>
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: The OP's original + looked nice and centered and rotated properly. Your example is off-center and it wobbles a little when it rotates, at least in my Chrome browser.

Comment: @lurker I just replaced it with an icon. Better?

Comment: Yes, better! Seems to work properly. Interestingly, though, the OP's also works properly for me, but maybe it's more browser version sensitive. By the way, I was not the one who down-voted your answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the effect I was going for. I suppose i will need to use an icon instead of text, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine for me, but I think that I understand what are you seeing, the issue is that the font that your are using to display the '+' symbol is bigger in the x axis, so when you rotate the view it's looking like it is moving vertically, but it is just an illusion, I can't upload images yet but try this yourself and you'll see it too.

Probably working with a different font may help.

Comment: I updated my post with a GIF of what I see. I suppose I should look into just using an icon instead of text. Thanks!